# Regex re non english characters

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

Today has been devoted to get a regex to work after paying a couple of people to write me one that does the following (neither of them could do it)...

Allow all English alphanumeric characters, allow all non-English alphanumeric characters eg Japanese, Spanish accented etc..., and allow this punctuation `)('$!.,&`

I thought I cracked it by eliminating all the punctuation I didn't want, but then realized it's going to let through a bunch of other unwanted characters eg bullet point...

```
_string = string.replace(/[\"\#\%\*\+\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\[\\\]\^\_\`\\{\|\}\~]/g, "");
```

(It's in AS3)

I've also been playing with combining `\p{L}` `\p{Nd}` with `)('$!.,&` figuring that they would let all alphanumeric characters in all languages through, and then the punctuation, but haven't cracked it.

So is there a way to do it (and for AS3?) - allow any alphanumeric character in any language, plus this punctuation `)('$!.,&`

I'm happy to pay someone who CAN do it.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: There is no `\p` in AS3 regex, and `\u` to specify Unicode character is not working from my experience (I tested on some sites that builds regex tester with Flex, which uses AS3's regex). So this is kinda impossible.

Comment: \u works fine in AS3, try this code for example: _"АБВГДэюя".match(/[\u0410-\u044f]+/g);_ it matches russian alphabet. I tryed this in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but it really doesn't work there, probably it's the bug of online as3 regex matchers.

Comment: I haven't come across \u yet - thanks for that. Is there a way to tell it to accept alphanumerics for all languages, or do you have to stipulate each language?

Comment: Yes, you have to add range for each language manually. I'll add some ranged in the answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\uXXXX` metasequence to specify unicode id of the character, but you have to add range for each language manually. Some ranges for most popular languages (non asian) that I worked with:

```
en:
AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz

ru:
АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя

pt:
ÁÂÃÀÇÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜáâãàçéêíóôõúü

de:
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöüßABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÜ

lv:
aābcčdeēfgģhiījkķlļmnņoprsštuūvzžAĀBCČDEĒFGĢHIĪJKĶLĻMNŅOPRSŠTUŪVZŽ

pl:
aąbcćdeęfghijklłmnńoóprsśtuwyzźżAĄBCĆDEĘFGHIJKLŁMNŃOÓPRSŚTUWYZŹŻ

tr:
abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprsştuüvyzABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZ

et:
abcdefghijklmnopqrsšzžtuvwõäöüxyABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSŠZŽTUVWÕÄÖÜXY

[ALL CHARS]:
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzÀÁÂÃÄÇÉÊÍÓÔÕÖÚÜßàáâãäçéêíóôõöúüĀāĄąĆćČčĒēĘęĞğĢģĪīİıĶķĻļŁłŃńŅņŚśŞşŠšŪūŹźŻżŽžЁАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяё

RegExp matches all [ALL CHARS]:
[\u0041-\u005A,\u0061-\u007A,\u00C0-\u00C4,\u00C7,\u00C9-\u00CA,\u00CD,\u00D3-\u00D6,\u00DA,\u00DC,\u00DF-\u00E4,\u00E7,\u00E9-\u00EA,\u00ED,\u00F3-\u00F6,\u00FA,\u00FC,\u0100-\u0101,\u0104-\u0107,\u010C-\u010D,\u0112-\u0113,\u0118-\u0119,\u011E-\u011F,\u0122-\u0123,\u012A-\u012B,\u0130-\u0131,\u0136-\u0137,\u013B-\u013C,\u0141-\u0146,\u015A-\u015B,\u015E-\u0161,\u016A-\u016B,\u0179-\u017E,\u0401,\u0410-\u044F,\u0451]+
```

Comment: Wow - ok - I think I'll be better off expanding on eliminating the unwanted characters, as it's going to become nuts if I add in Asian languages.  But thank you for the post fsbmain - I was unaware of this method using \u.